# How to generate a web3 object?

Tags: web3js

The following example does not hang.

```
$ cat main.js 
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.getAccounts()
    .then((accounts) => {
        console.log(accounts);
    })
```

But the following code hangs. Does anybody know why?

```
$ cat main.js 
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const web3 = new (require('web3'))("ws://localhost:8545");
web3.eth.getAccounts()
    .then((accounts) => {
        console.log(accounts);
    })
```

Comment: that's a javascript issue please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787074/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-new-require

Comment: for websockets default port is 8546, if you are running geth node. btw how you have configured your geth node.